# Как задать background в приложении OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры, glsl

У меня неправильно задаётся фон. Всё что мне нужно - это наложить фон перед 3d сценой, но у меня почему-то фон перекрывает сцену. Пробовал менять порядок отрисовки и менять шейдеры "на лету". Результат либо тот же, либо вообще без 3d сцены, а только фон.

Сейчас выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код рендеринга (фактически просто чуть-чуть изменённый с OpenGL tutorial):

```cpp
        glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Связывание текстуры
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);

        // Рендеринг ящика
        shader.use();
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        unsigned int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "model");
        unsigned int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);

        glBindVertexArray(vp.VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vp.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

        glm::mat4 model2 = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view2 = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 projection2 = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        unsigned int modelLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "model");
        unsigned int viewLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "view");
        model2 = glm::translate(model2, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.7f, 0.5f));
        view2 = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, -2.f, 2.75f),
                            glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                            glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        projection2 = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)(SCR_WIDTH / SCR_HEIGHT), 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc2, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model2));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc2, 1, GL_FALSE, &view2[0][0]);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection2);
        glBindVertexArray(vp.VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vp.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: обмен содержимым front- и back- буферов. Отслеживание событий ввода/вывода (была ли нажата/отпущена кнопка, перемещен курсор мыши и т.п.)
        glfwSwapBuffers(app.mWindow.getGLFWWindow());
```

Код вертикального шейдера простейший:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
 
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
 
void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Я также пробовал создать отдельный шейдер для фона и менять через `glUseProgram`, но это не помогло. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: С отключённым буфером глубины ОК. Но он мне всё равно нужен для 3d сцены

Comment: Если используете буфер глубины, то его надо заполнять так, чтобы значение глубины у фона было меньше, чем глубина того, что рисуется потом.

Comment: @user7860670, я только начал изучать openGL. А как оно заполняется? Я сейчас добавил `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` и оно работает. Есть другие более правильные способы?

Comment: Оно обычно автоматически заполняется глубиной каждого нарисованного пикселя. Указывайте у спрайта с фоном большую глубину (z).

Answer (score -1):

Да, а потом встанет вопрос какого цвета фон, как его выбрать из списка стандартных ColorDlg для Windows или лучше текстуру наложить. В общем кода будет много. Проще взять готовое решение фреймворка надстройки над OpenGL, платформы GLScene - там фон бэкграунда окна OpenGL порта вывода в компоненте TGLSceneViewer настраивается в свойстве типа TGLSceneBuffer Buffer, в выпадающем списке цветов.
Например, было так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
стало так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну я решил сам. Вопрос в текстуре не встанет т.к это и есть текстура. Я честно говоря завис на другом вопросе с OpenGL и перешёл на vulkan. Уже забыл об этом вопросе. Но этот я решил отдельным пайплайном под фоны (у меня несколько слоёв) там в шейдере это можно редактировать через `gl_fragdepth`. Но все равно спасибо за участие ;)